# TAdoquery Append Post: Is there a limit on the amount of Append before Post?

Tags: sql, delphi, post, append, delphi-7

Recently, I wanted to insert about 10,000,000 records into DB for some test in Delphi7. I appended 5000 per time, and then did Post. The whole process took a lot of time.

So I want to change the post amount, about 10000, 100000... It seemed to work smoothly.

So I am confused about is there a limit on the amount of Append before Post. I google a lot, but found little.

Is there anybody can tell me something?

Comment: If you want to insert that many records I suggest you look at 'bulk insert' options for your specific database. Writing to a text file and bulk inserting that is way way faster.

Comment: the fastest performance you can get is using TADOQuery and parametrized insert statements.

Comment: @whosrdaddy The **fastest** is *bulk insert*

Comment: faYeap,I have tried BCP and Bulk insert.They work really fantastically

Comment: @SirRufo, I mean with ADO, I know what bulk insert is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert as many records as you like with `Append` and only call `Post` after all are done. Every `Append` will internally call `Post` to save the last added record.

BTW, this shouldn't have any influence on the time needed.

Comment: U'r totally right.I have done some tests.So I think the post size is decided by the situation.